# Ember.js model not showing after refresh

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <p>{{#link-to 'mytest'}}My Test{{/link-to}}</p>

    <p>{{#link-to 'posts'}}POSTS{{/link-to}}</p>

    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="mytest">
    <p>...</p>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
    <ul>
        {{#each model}}
        <li>{{id}} -- {{#link-to 'post' this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>

    <p>
        {{outlet}}
    </p>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>

    <p>{{excerpt}}</p>
</script>

<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ember-1.7.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<!-- to activate the test runner, add the "?test" query string parameter -->
<script src="tests/runner.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my JS:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('mytest');
    this.resource('posts', function (){
        this.resource('post', { path: ':post_id' });
    });
});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
       return posts;
   }
});

App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params) {
       return posts.findBy('id', params.post_id);
   }
});

var posts = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'title': 'first!',
        'excerpt': 'firccccccccst!'
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': 'second!',
        'excerpt': 'sssdsddsd!'
    },
];
```

When I change this:

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params) {
       return posts.findBy('id', params.post_id);
   }
});
```

to this:

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params) {
       return {
        'id': 1,
        'title': 'first!',
        'excerpt': 'firccccccccst!'
    }
   }
});
```

it works.

What's wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is that you're using a plain old javascript array as if it's an `Ember.Array` (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html).  Try using `Ember.Array( posts )` before you call `.findBy()`.

Comment: @JoshPadnick adding Ember.Array( posts ); make the page blank.

Comment: I saw you were using the Ember Starter Kit, so I downloaded it from scratch and replaced my `index.html` with yours (only the part between the `<body>` tags), and my `js/app.js` with yours entirely, and it worked fine.  I did notice the latest from GitHub now uses `handlebars-v1.3.0.js`.  Is that the issue?  Otherwise, download from scratch, and do exactly what I did to get it working.